# How can we replace kubectl commands mentioned in playbook to equivalent ansible module

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, ansible, kubernetes-pod

Here we are trying to use the nginx secret for different namespace (abc here).
Although this playbook works fine locally but when trying to execute in AKS cluster against pod getting below error which is obivous because kubeconfig is not present in those pods.

######## Error message ##########

```
   "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 127,
    "start": "2022-02-14 19:56:12.421969",
    "stderr": "/bin/sh: kubectl: command not found",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "/bin/sh: kubectl: command not found"
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
```

**Ansible playbook:**

```
     ---
        
        - name: Retrive the secret from nginx namespace and convert it for abc namespace
          hosts: localhost
          connection: local
        
          tasks:
          - name: Get Secret from k8s for nginx namespace
            shell: kubectl get secret nginx-default-cert -n nginx -o yaml
            register: nginx_default_secret
        
        #  - name: k8s nginx_default_secret data
        #    debug:
        #      msg: "{{ nginx_default_secret.stdout }}"
        
          - name: copy contents of latest nginx_default_secret to a tmp file abc-server-cert
            copy: 
              content: "{{ nginx_default_secret.stdout }}{{'\n'}}"
              dest: /tmp/abc-server-cert.yaml
        
          - name: Change certificate name from nginx-default-cert to abc-server-cert
            replace:
              path: /tmp/abc-server-cert.yaml
              regexp: 'nginx-default-cert'
              replace: "abc-server-cert"
        
          - name: Change namespace name from nginx to abc
            replace:
              path: /tmp/abc-server-cert.yaml
              regexp: 'nginx'
              replace: "abc"
        
             ######### apply the cert to abc namespace #########
        
          - name: Apply the abc-server-cert on abc namespace 
            # become: yes
            # become_user: kube
            shell: |
              kubectl apply -f /tmp/abc-server-cert.yaml -n abc
        
             ######### pod_restart #########
        
          - name: restart the pod of abc namespace 
            # become: yes
            # become_user: kube
            shell: |
              kubectl rollout restart statefulset abc-server -n abc
            register: abc_status
```

Now need help to understand how can we replace the kubectl commands with equivalent ansible modules to execute it successfully.

Open to any suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question that you like to translate a task like

```yaml
tasks:

- name: Execute 'kubectl' command
  shell: kubectl ...
```

from `shell` module to a specified one to [Manage Kubernetes (K8s) objects](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/k8s_module.html).

You may have a look into the [Kubernetes Collection for Ansible](https://galaxy.ansible.com/kubernetes/core) and the [Modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/index.html#modules).

Comment: Yeah ..i tried to work with below but couldn't register it in file
`
 tasks:
   - name: Get Secret from k8s for nginx namespace
     kubernetes.core.k8s_info:
       api_version: v1
       kind: Secret
       name: nginx-default-cert
       namespace: nginx
     register: nginx_default_secret
`